# Consuming a web api inside a web application project when using Kubernetes enabled in Docker Desktop and Helm

Tags: visual-studio, docker, kubernetes

I have managed to deploy a simple ASP.NET MVC application to Kubernetes (Kubernetes enabled in Docker Desktop) using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@bterkaly/running-asp-net-applications-in-kubernetes-a-detailed-step-by-step-approach-96c98f273d1a.  My manifest looks like this:

```
environment: development

apphost: k8s

label:
  name: aspnet3core

container:
  name: aspnet3
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  image: aspnet3k8s
  tag: v1
  port: 80
replicas: 3

service:
  port: 8888
  type: ClusterIP
```

I have also managed to deploy a simple Web API project to Kubernetes using this tutorial: https://dev.to/wolnikmarcin/run-asp-net-core-3-on-kubernetes-with-helm-1o01.  My manifest looks  like this:

```
//myDeploy.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dotnetlinux
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dotnetlinux
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: "brunoterkaly/dotnetlinux"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: dotnetlinux
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80

//myService.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dotnetlinux
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: dotnetlinux
```

I am now trying to workout how to call the web api from the MVC project.  I cannot find an explanation online of how to do this.  I was hoping there would be a sample project on GitHub, but I can't find it.

I am using Docker Desktop with Kubernetes enabled and Visual Studio 2019 (Kubernetes/Helm).

Comment: How have you tried to reach out your API? You can call your service "dotnetlinux" on port :80, or if you run a `kubectl get services` you will be able to see the IP of the service, then you can also use that. Not a good approach though, as the IP of the service will change every time your service is restarted.

Comment: @Juliano Costa, I see.  So I should be able to do this: http://dotnetlinux:80/api/myMethod/..... Is that right?

Comment: If I understood your case properly, yes... Are you able to try it?

Comment: You set the API as `LoadBalancer` (meaning it's exposed to the internet) but you mention you want it to be accessible by the MVC, am I wrong to think you actually want to expose the mvc to the outside and the api only inside? And yes, the mvc can access the api using the service name `dotnetlinux:80/api`. Did you succeed? let me know if you need further help with your project on kubernetes.

Comment: @willrof, thanks.  At the moment I am trying to resolve my other kubernetes question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010108/cannot-delete-kubernetes-application could you take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting my comment as an answer:

To access your POD you need to call your service "dotnetlinux" on port :80, something like `dotnetlinux:80/yourAPI`.

You can also run `kubectl get services` to get the IP of the service, then use that. Not a good approach though, as the IP of the service will change every time your service is restarted.

In this [documentation page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) there is a lot of details about Services and the sessions Motivation and Service resources explain why Services are needed, and how they help you in your case.